# found 1 results, but was looking for 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the carrierwave gem in a rails 3 app for uploading profile pictures. On a user's homepage there is a link to change their profile picture. To get the id of the profile picture record I have the following in the userhome controller:

```
  @profile_picture = ProfilePicture.find("user_id = ?", current_user.id)

  # if no profile picture record, create one
  if @profile_picture.empty?
    ProfilePicture.create(:picture => "", :user_id => current_user.id )
  end
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Couldn't find all ProfilePictures with IDs (user_id = ?, 1) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)
```

Haven't seen this error before and a web search didn't produce anything useful.

Thanks.

Comment: your error is due to an error on your first `find` line, but below I've shown a way to do everything you posted on one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish all of that (and fix your error) with one line:

```
@profile_picture = ProfilePicture.find_or_create_by_user_id(:user_id => current_user.id, :picture => "")
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, but I believe there's an error here. The find_or_create_by_user_id method should take two arguments: the user id first, and an optional hash of other attributes second: f_o_c_b_u_i(current_user.id, :picture => "")

Answer (score 2):

The [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) method takes a list of ids, not an SQL snippet. You passed two arguments, and it assumed they were both ids. It found nothing. Instead, I think you want this:

```
@profile_picture = ProfilePicture.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am **very** new to RoR, but i was wondering if you can user `ProfilePicture.find_by_owner(owner_id)`
or

```
ProfilePicture.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ProfilePicture WHERE owner.id = current_user.id")
```

Dunno, just throwing my two cents (and trying to learn Ruby on Rails)

--EDIT--

By the way, i think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979625/retrieving-objects-from-the-database-advanced-array-conditions) could be useful.